# c# SMTP PLAIN AUTH format

Tags: c#, authentication, smtp

This post will be a bit longer. I am working on a c# SMTP server. I try to get this server to work with one special mailer. Today I'm working on the auth module. The client should sent the user+password as one string decoded as BASE64 string. I used as username "1" and as password "2". The third party software I used sent to my server:

> AUTH PLAIN ADEAMg==

"ADEAMg==" is the string I explained above. I checked online Base64 decoder and all of them told me "MTI=" is the correct base64 decoded string of "12". Anybody an idea what kind of format the string "ADEAMg==" is? It should be built out of "12". I don't know how to encode this string to get a clear result. Online encoder websites show me some special symbols, like "specialsymbol1specialsymbol2". I tried to use .Replace() to get these specialsymbols deleted, but all I tried doesn't work. All in all using .Replace wouldn't be the best solution, so I ask you, maybe you know what kind of format ("ADEAMg==") is.

Regards;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MTI=` is Base64 encoded ASCII "12" string. The binary representation (hex bytes) of this ASCII string is as follows:

```
31 32
```

`ADEAMg==` is Base64 encoded Unicode (UTF-16BE) "12" string. The binary representation (hex bytes) of this UTF-16BE string is as follows:

```
00 31 00 32
```

Online Base64 decoders tries to show these UTF-16BE bytes in one byte charset so you get something like this:

```
�1�2
```

More about UTF-16: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

---

**EDIT:** this code snippet decodes `ADEAMg==` to `12` string:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("ADEAMg==");
string result = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the  field of an array (ADEANg== is one field of an array) converted, so I can make a simple if check, like :  if password =="12"

Comment: @Pekinese added code snippet which decodes `ADEANg==` to string

Comment: I used this code, the result is "16" and not "12", where's my fault? `string[] p = new string [] {"ADEANg=="};
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(p[0]);
            string result =  Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: No fault, `ADEANg==` decoded is `16`, in question is different: `ADEAMg==`